# Prove that, if $A\subset B$, then $A\cup B = B$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Q1: If $A\subset B$ then $A\cup B=B$.

My attempt:

If $A\subset B$, it means $\forall x \in A $ we have $x\in B$

$A\cup B$ means that either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ or *both*.

We already know that $\forall x \in A $ we have $x\in B$, thus $A\cup B$ will just be the set $B$.

Q2: If $(A\cup B)\subset (B\cup C) $ then $A\subset B$.

If $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ or *both* then $x\in B$ or $x\in C$ or *both*.

There may be some $x\in A$ such that $x\notin C$ but I don't understand how to write it formally.

Can someone please verify both of my attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871258/prove-or-disprove-that-x-cap-y-x-implies-that-x-cup-y-y/3871262#3871262). The second claim is not true in general.

Take $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{2\}$ and $C = \{1,3\}$. Thus, $A\cup B = \{1,2\} \subset \{1,2,3\} = B\cup C$ but $A\not\subset B$.

Hopefully this helps.